# Puppeter how to prevent stopping program on error

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, puppeteer

Directly to the problem that I noticed while creating puppeteer automata.
I check if element exists like this:

```
const check = async () => {
  let state = null
  await page.waitForSelector(els.configurationBtn)
    .then(res => res ? state = true : state = false)
    .catch(() => { state = false })
    enter code here

  return state
}
```

But it is not a smooth way to prevent stopping the program when `page.waitForSelector` throws an error.

My question is How can I wait for the element (check if exist) and return Boolean - `true` if the element exists and false if the element doesn't exist or when `page.waitForSelector` throws a timeout error.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `await` you can just use `try...catch`. No need for `.then` or `.catch`... that's the whole point of using `await` in the first place.

```
const check = async () => {
  try {
    return await page.waitForSelector(els.configurationBtn) != null;
  } catch {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Or just use `.then` and pass a second argument to it. The second function is called when the promise is rejected.

```
const check = () => page.waitForSelector(els.configurationBtn)
  .then(res => res != null, () => false);
```